# Nav working in all versions of IE except IE11

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I've got a pretty interesting problem, and no doubt, it's caused by IE.

The issue I'm having is the main nav #main-menu is going behind the div directly underneath it in IE11. I've tested it in all other versions of IE and it's working fine. I've inspected in IE11 and I can do the style below and it will show itself.

```css
#main-menu {top: -50px;}
```

I'm not entirely sure what is causing it to do this. It's pretty weird if you ask me.

HTML layout (example of the exact layout, omitted links)

```html
<header id="header">
    <div id="header-wrap">
        <div id="company-info"></div>
        <div id="main-menu"></div>
    </div>
</header>
```

**EDIT** I've found my own solution after more inspection.

Here's what happened:

- `#company-info` had a height set to 100%
- `#header-wrap` did not have a height specified
- When I specified a height of 100% to `#header-wrap` the problem was solved
- `#company-info` was pushing `#main-menu` down because its parent didn't have a specified height

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: Alright. I'll grab it real quick

Comment: Hi Ryan, please don't repeatedly add fluff like "Thanks" to posts; it's removed for a reason!

Answer (score -3):

You could use something like [normalise.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) this will make sure all the default styles will be the same for all browsers

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However that won't work with this. I know there is some way to get this done through some editing of my CSS

Comment: This does not really answer the question.